# Flutter + Firebase How can I add DisplayName when creating account with Email and Password

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm new to Flutter and really, really new to firebase.

I'm trying to create a user via the createUserWithEmailAndPasswordMethod. I've successfully created one, but I'm trying to improve it by allowing the user to enter the desired displayname

My code is as follows:

```
if (pwdInputController.text ==
                              confirmPwdInputController.text) {
                            FirebaseAuth.instance
                                .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                                    email: emailInputController.text,
                                    password: pwdInputController.text)
                                .then((AuthResult currentUser) => Firestore.instance
                                    .collection("userInfo")
                                    .document(currentUser.user.email)
                                    .setData({
                                      "name": fullNameInputController.text,
                                      "phone": phoneInputController.text,
                                      "bloodgroup":
                                          bloodgroupInputController.text,
                                      "last_donated":
                                          lastdateInputController.text,
                                      "alcohalic":
                                          alcohalicInputController.text,
                                      "verified": verifiedInputController.text,
                                      "#donated": donatednoInputController.text,
                                      "location": null,
                                      "age": ageInputController.text,
                                      "userid": currentUser.user.uid,
                                      "email": currentUser.user.email,
                                    })
                                    .then((result) => {
                                          Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                                              context,
                                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                                  builder: (context) =>
                                                      HomePage(
                                                        title:
                                                            fullNameInputController
                                                                .text,
                                                        uid: currentUser
                                                            .user.email,
                                                      )),
                                              (_) => false),
                                          fullNameInputController.clear(),
                                          emailInputController.clear(),
                                          pwdInputController.clear(),
                                          confirmPwdInputController.clear(),
                                          phoneInputController.clear(),
                                          bloodgroupInputController.clear(),
                                          lastdateInputController.clear(),
                                          alcohalicInputController.clear(),
                                          verifiedInputController.clear(),
                                          donatednoInputController.clear(),
                                          locationInputController.clear(),
                                          ageInputController.clear()
                                        })
                                    .catchError((err) => print(err)))
                                .catchError((err) => print(err));
                          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the display name to firebase auth using the following code:

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.updateProfile(displayName: "JohnDoe");
```

If you decide to add a display photo in future you can do so by :

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.updateProfile(displayName: "JohnDoe",photoURL: "URL of the photo");
```

You can access the name and image URL using the following code:

```
User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
              String name = user.displayName;
              String imgUrl = user.photoURL;
```